# What is the best way to smooth solid exported from Fusion 360 with a circular hole

Tags: modeling, mesh, smooth

Shade Smooth doesn't seem to work with this geometry, as you can see from the following screenshots.

What would be the best workflow for making the inside tube (and the rim) be perfectly smooth?

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/7lszcvm9oyh3fs17y7p32/Shade-Smooth-How.blend?rlkey=080oqd98o1qifirqw7zhsox5g&dl=0)

Without Shade Smooth:
[image]

With Shade Smooth:
[image]

Mesh:
[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I’m open to suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing dissolve these edges:

[image]

You have bad split normals, go into the *Object Data* panel and *Clear Custom Split Normals Data*:

[image]

Then enable the *Auto Smooth* and set the *Angle* to 80°:

[image]

You also need to remove the bad shading that we can still see here:

[image]

Select all in *Edit* mode and <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*, then create thes edges to prepare the topology to a correct inset:

[image]

Select all these faces and <kbd>i</kbd> to inset:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Very cool, thank you for this. The object is a solid exported from Fusion 360 and the topology always gets a little screwy with that workflow.  But the upside is that I always improve my geometry skills trying to fix it!